# How can I check that the trademark(™) character is set correctly in my Oracle database?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

### How can I check that the trademark(™) character is set correctly in my Oracle database?

I expect it to be stored using UTF-8 encoding.

I have a value stored in a Salesforce.com field that looks like this from the GUI (notice the trademark character):

```
Chuck Norris's Roundhouse Kick™
```

I'm using Informatica to replicate it to an Oracle database.  My database is set to use the AL32UTF8 encoding.

#### How it shows up in SQL Developer

When I query my table using SQL Developer, the trademark symbol shows up as *a rectangle* (black border, white fill).

#### How it shows up in HTML

When I export it from SQL Developer using the UTF-8 encoding into an HTML document, and open it in Chrome, the trademark symbol does not appear at all.  When I open it in IE, the it appears as a rectangle again.  In Firefox, it's a rectangle with `00` in the top half and `99` in the bottom half.  All three browsers interpret the HTML doc using UTF-8.

#### How it shows up in text editors

Opening the same HTML doc in Notepad and Notepad++, the trademark symbol shows up as a rectangle.  If I use the Hex Viewer plugin for Notepad++ I see the byte encoding is `C2 99`.  That seems to be the [correct encoding for the trademark symbol in UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0099/index.htm).

When I open document in MS Write, the trademark character looks like this: `Â™`.

#### When I get the value programmatically

Using Python, when I get the value from the database, the trademark character is replaced with '\xbf' -- [the inverted question mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bf/index.htm), but *that* character is not even properly encoded as far as I can tell because it's missing at least one leading byte (depending on the specific encoding)

```
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>> con = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'password', 'db')
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('select * from trademark')
<__builtin__.OracleCursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to username@db>>
>>> records = cur.fetchall()
>>> records[0][0]
"Chuck Norris's Roundhouse Kick\xbf"
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to validate the data stored in my Oracle database using all of the above methods.  I'd settle for someone just validating that what I saw in the Hex Viewer was enough of a "test" ;)

Comment: Code 0x99 is the trademark symbol in the Windows 1252 code page.  And several others.  Whatever you found back in that dbase was not encoded in utf-8.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character literal ™ you posted is not U+0099 (a control character), but U+2122 (TRADE MARK SIGN).

The Unicode spec [defines](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) U+0099 as follows:

```
0099;<control>;Cc;0;BN;;;;;N;;;;;
```

So, it doesn't even have a name and I haven't gone digging round the spec to find out what this character is for.

Decoding U+0099 in Windows does result in a trademark grapheme. I guess this is a bug.

The correct byte sequence for the TRADE MARK SIGN (U+2122) in UTF-8 is `E2 84 A2`.

Comment: You're right.  The value is not being encoded correctly when written to the database by Informatica.  Writing the value from my own test program, I was able to retrieve the trademark symbol.  We're looking into what went wrong in the write, or the handling of the value before the write.

Comment: Since U+2122 encodes as 0x99 in windows-1252, I would guess something is using a default "ANSI" encoding during some transcoding operation.

Answer (score 2):

Just for any future reference, because the author did not bother posting a fix.
It's indeed an Informatica problem, what is needed:

1. Change connection properties in odbc.ini on Informatica box, add "IANAAppCodePage=106" to the connections that need UTF8.
2. Change connection properties in Informatica itself for the connection and add "Codepage=Utf-8" in "Connection Manager -> Connections -> Relational ->  -> Edit"

Answer (score 0):

if you are saving this string for output in an html doc use: `&trade;` the html entity for the trademark symbol.

if you are using this string for non html purposes decode the string at runtime use:

```
import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
s = h.unescape('&trade;')
```

see:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp
http://fredericiana.com/2010/10/08/decoding-html-entities-to-text-in-python/