# special characters in json getting encoded

Tags: java, json, encoding, jboss, gson

I have a java object which I convert to json using google gson (version 1.4). String contains a special character ™ which is getting encoded. for example:

input to gson.toJson():

Deals of the Day, web bustersÃ‚Â™, electrics

output:

Deals of the Day, web bustersÃ‚\u0099, electrics

I have also disabled HTML escaping for gson - Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create() but I don't think this character has anything to do with that.

This issue is happening when I am running it on jboss and linux.

same code does not convert ™ to \u0099 when I run it on jboss and windows.

Can some one help me guide to the areas I can look to fix this issue. Is there any thing on linux or jboss setting I can check or is it completely related to gson utility I am using? I am running jbossEAP6 on java version 6 and gson version is 1.4.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Could this be a character encoding issue? Are you calling `getBytes()` or `new String(bytes)` and not specifying UTF-8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check that the trademark(™) character is set correctly in my Oracle database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341274/how-can-i-check-that-the-trademark-character-is-set-correctly-in-my-oracle-da)